# Why does Kernel Density fail in model with ERROR 000865?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, kernel-density, error-000865

I am attempting to build a model using variables for automation. (see below)

[image: Model]

The problem I am having is when the model attempts to run the Kernel Density. It seems as if the Kernel Density will not recognize %FilePreFix%_ts_cd even though a shapefile is created. Below is the error I get.

[image: Error]

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but do any other files with names of the form "0113_ts_cd.*" exist in the C:\MonthlyReport\Jan13 folder?  Perhaps files with extensions .shp, .shx, and .dbf?

Comment: Have you tried adding a ".shp" extension to the path (e.g. ...\0113_ts_cd.shp")?

Comment: Adding the ".shp" worked!! I thought we tried that yesterday. I guess not. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aaron suggested, I had to add ".shp" extension to the path (e.g. ...\0113_ts_cd.shp") for the model to run.